# Creating a SplashScreen/LoadingScreen with timer

Tags: c#, forms, timer, splash-screen

I created a working `SplashScreen/LoadingScreen`.

I used the following code to show and close the LoadinScreen:

```
   LoadingScreen LS = new LoadingScreen();
   LS.Show();

   databaseThread = new Thread(CheckDataBase);
   databaseThread.Start();
   databaseThread.Join();

   LS.Close();
```

This code is doing a great job for me, showing and closing the `LoadingScreen`.

The problem is: I got some text on the `LoadingScreen`, that says: `Loading Application...`

I want to create a Timer to let the dots at the end of the text(Label) do the following:

```
Loading Application.
```

1 second later:

```
Loading Application..
```

1 second Later:

```
Loading Application...
```

I suppose that I need to add a `timer` to the `Load_event` of the `LoadingScreen form`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered a simple animated GIF?

Comment: Hmm, that is one smart solution, will search for some loading .GIF's

Comment: One thing, the GIF will hang because it is running in a thread.

Comment: Are you sure?  EVERYTHING runs in threads.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved the problem using the BackGroundWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
class LoadingScreen
{
    Timer timer0;
    TextBox mytextbox = new TextBox();
    public LoadingScreen()
    {
        timer0 = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer0.Enabled = true;
        timer0.Elapsed += new Action<object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs>((object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            switch (mytextbox.Text) 
            {
                case "Loading":
                    mytextbox.Text = "Loading.";
                    break;
                case "Loading.":
                    mytextbox.Text = "Loading..";
                    break;
                case "Loading..":
                    mytextbox.Text = "Loading...";
                    break;
                case "Loading...":
                    mytextbox.Text = "Loading";
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
A good way to prevent UI thread to block waiting for database operation is to move the database operation to a BackgroundWorker ex:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    LoadingScreen LS;   
    public void Main()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker BW;
        BW.DoWork += BW_DoWork;
        BW.RunWorkerCompleted += BW_RunWorkerCompleted;
        LS = new LoadingScreen();
        LS.Show();
    }

    private void BW_DoWork(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do here anything you have to do with the database
    }

    void BW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LS.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh? Elapsed events will fire each second (notice the "1000" value in the constructor). Each time it fires, the textbox content will be update like:

Loading
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...

Comment: Mmm.. You're partially right, 'cause I've never initialized the textbox content with "Loading". Simply put mytextbox.Text = "Loading"; before  timer0.Elapsed += ***

Comment: I have one question at last, I think this will never work because I'am using a thread and the whole form hangs while this thread is working

Comment: This is because you are Joining the main (UI) thread with the databaseThread.
You could create another thread that waits for databaseThread to be end, or (better way, imho) let databaseThread close the loading splashscreen when it has done and let UI thread runs.. Even better, you could put it into a BackgroundWorker instead of a Thread. Then, you could close the splash screen in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: Do you have an good example for a splashscreen incombination with a background worker? because I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 300;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(methodToUpdateText);
timer.Start();
```